# How would you determine whether an array of pixels resemble a line?

Tags: python, algorithm, math, line

If I have a 2d array of pixels, how can I efficiently determine whether the points resemble a line? (Not determine the line itself)

My current method is to measure the distances from each point to the best fit line and if the std.dev of these distances is greater than ~1.4 I treat it as a line. This approach is pretty inefficient but accurate enough for what I need.

Is there a faster and maybe more elegant method to achieve this?

Comment: I assume this is what you're using right now? https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html

Comment: I was hoping to determine whether it is a line or not, rather than to calculate the line itself. I felt there may be a faster, more mathematical method?

Comment: Instead of checking whether "it's a line", check for "it's not a line"? Build an average slope using a sliding window, and if either the average bounces around a lot, or a new point is drastically off from its predicted position, it's not a line. At worst this requires checking all points, and if the last one passes, it _is_ a line.

Answer (score 0):

Linear regression definitely works, although there are definitely some good alternatives. Use Hough Transform. It's a nifty feature extraction technique that can detect lines or circles. Search it up and do some research on how to use it.

Here is a good video to get a fundamental understanding of it. I would definitely suggest watching more and reading up on some more resources to get a better comprehension of it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5zAT6yTHvP0&ab_channel=DigitalSreeni

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Calculating the standard deviation from the best fit line should be pretty efficient.  I would do essentially the same thing using [principal component analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis).

First you calculate the 2x2 [covariance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix) of all your points in linear time, and then find the two eigenvalues.

The bigger eigenvalue is the variance of the point cloud in the major direction, and the smaller eigenvalue is the variance in the minor direction.  `sqrt(small_eigenvalue / big_eigenvalue)` is the ratio of the corresponding standard deviations.  This is approximately the "aspect ratio" of the point cloud along the major and minor directions, which pretty well describes how "line-like" it is.